# How to refresh web sourced images in GUI

Tags: java, image, swing, user-interface, web

I've created a simple GUI application in Java, that displays certain images sourced from the web in different sections.

What i'm having trouble doing, is refreshing the images after a certain period of time (specifically, 40 seconds). I need the application to get the image from the web again, and place it in one of three JPanels, every 40 seconds as long as the app is running.

This is the code used to display the images when the application starts up:

```
try {
    BufferedImage cameraOne = ImageIO.read(new URL("IMAGE LINK HERE"));
    BufferedImage cameraTwo = ImageIO.read(new URL("IMAGE LINK HERE"));
    BufferedImage cameraThree = ImageIO.read(new URL("IMAGE LINK HERE"));

    cPanel1 = new CameraPanel(new ImageIcon(cameraOne).getImage());
    cPanel2 = new CameraPanel(new ImageIcon(cameraTwo).getImage());
    cPanel3 = new CameraPanel(new ImageIcon(cameraThree).getImage());
} catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
    throw new Error("One of the cameras you are trying to connect to doesn't exist!");
} catch (IOException ex) {
    throw new Error("CCTV couldn't connect to the required camera feeds!");
}
```

This is the code i'm using to attempt to schedule the image refreshes:

```
final ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);

final Runnable refreshTask = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {

        // I need help here
    }
};

final ScheduledFuture<?> refreshHandler = scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(refreshTask, 10, 40, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

This is the CameraPanel class, as seen in the code used to display the images when the application starts up:

```
class CameraPanel extends JPanel {
   private Image img;

    public CameraPanel(BufferedImage cameraImage) {
        this(new ImageIcon(cameraImage).getImage());
    }

    public CameraPanel(Image img) {
        this.img = img;
        Dimension size = new Dimension(img.getWidth(null), img.getHeight(null));
        setPreferredSize(size);
        setMinimumSize(size);
        setMaximumSize(size);
        setSize(size);
        setLayout(null);
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
    }
}
```

Any solutions? Thanks.

The full class i've created can be found at http://pastebin.com/nRNHHkfx

Comment: I would assume that you would need; a refernce to the URL to be refreshed; a reference to the camera panel associated with the image; a method by which the newly downloaded image can be re-applied to the camera panel and the camera panel updated

Comment: It's especially the image being applied to the camera panel that i'm having trouble with, as well as updating the camera panel. I tried repainting cPanel1, but it just created a duplicate image behind the original image.

Comment: You need to change the image reference to the reference you've just downloaded.  This means you need a `setImage` method in the `CameraPanel` so that once you've downloaded, you can pass that reference `CameraPanel` and repaint it...